# Probability for matching hexagons number.

Tags: probability, geometry, rotations

I have some interesting math problem.

Let say we have `n`number of hexagons. Each hexagon has random numbers in his corners from `1` to `k`. Each hexagon can be rotated as many times as we want. What is the probability for `m` - hexagons to match with others. For matching we count that can be placed together side by side and in each corner is the same number.

All `n` hexagons are on the pile and you can take one by one and place them where you like them to be and rotate them as you want.

For example :

two matching hexagon would look like :

[image]

and three matching hexagons would look like :

[image]

Comment: You need to mention the configuration in which the hexagons are arranged.

Comment: They are not. Think of them like they are on the one big pile and you take one by one and you arrange it like you want. (Like puzzle)